# How do I use datasources in CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, mongodb, cakephp-2.0

My MongoDB datasource is located in *plugins/mongodb*.

According to [the new class loader in 2.0](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/20-class-loading) I should do this:

```
App::uses('MongodbSource', 'Mongodb.Model/Datasource');
```

But how do I initiate it?

Or is it best practice to use the ConnectionManager? If so, how do I import it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you WANT to use your way and loading this datasource "by hand" and not like Matt said, you would initiate it like this:

```
# /path/to/your/datasource
class MongoDbDatasource {...} //check how this class is named!
```

Within your file where you load it you can do this:

```
App::uses('MongodbSource', 'Mongodb.Model/Datasource');
$mongodb = new MongoDbDatasource();
```

But as said, the databsae configuration would be the better way:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'database' => 'mydbname',
    'host' => 'yourhost',
    'port' => 'yourport',
    'login' => 'yourlogin',
    'password' => 'yourpassword'
);
```

Now you just have so add `CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');` to your `bootstrap.php` so your plugin will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your database configuration which datasource to use:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, then you need to tell your model which database configuration to use. in 1.3 you add "public $useDbConfig = 'mongodb';" for example.