# Cakephp 2.3.7 Url Wiriting Not Properly Config/ Undefined Index: Datasource

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to spin up a application I downloaded from a repository. It is built with Cakephp 2.3.7. The first error I am getting is URL Writing is not properly configured on your server.I have checked my .htaccess files and everything is ok. I have check Apache and LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is as such. Not to sure what else to check. The other notice I am getting is Undefined Index: Datasource. I went to my config file as it is as follows:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'icgw',
    'prefix' => '',
);

var $array = array(
    'datasource' => 'Array'
);

var $test = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'test_database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
);
}
```

That said I did try 
    var $array = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/MySql'
    );

Unfortunately I had no luck. Any thoughts on this? Im not familiar with working in Cakephp 2.3.7. I use Cakephp 1.3.

Comment: Search is your friend, before making a new question always use the search. [Book datasource](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html), [How do I use datasources in CakePHP 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408629/how-do-i-use-datasources-in-cakephp-2), [Cake php Datasource class MySQL could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208855/cake-php-datasource-class-mysql-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the Undefined Index: Datasource error. This is what I did.

Instead of

```
var $default = array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
'persistent' => false,
'host' => 'localhost',
'login' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'icgw',
'prefix' => '',
);

var $array = array(
'datasource' => 'Array'
);
```

I did this.

```
var $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'icgw',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```